# Firestore increment replacing or deleting Field

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use the [Increment function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#c_12) to keep track of how many alerts of a specific container are stored on Firestore. To do that, on each API call that contains an alert I'm updating this counter by doing this:

```
db.collection("container")
                        .document(entryDataDto.getCollectionId())
                        .update("alarmCount", FieldValue.increment(1));
```

I have also tried like this:

```
Map<String, Object> update = new HashMap<>();
update.put("alarmCount", FieldValue.increment(1));

db.collection("container")
                        .document(entryDataDto.getCollectionId())
                        .set(update, SetOptions.merge());
```

These two snippets of code works seemingly the same but they run into the same problem, they're quite unpredictable.

From what I've tested 4 things may occur:

1. If the field don't already exist it will be created with value 1;
2. If the field already exists, it can be replaced with the same field with value 1 (by replaced I literally mean the old field is deleted and a new one take it's place);
3. If the field already exists, it can be incremented but the field is deleted right after the value is incremented;
4. And finally the rarest of them, if the field already exists, it is incremented by 1.

These 4 behaviors are quite random and I couldn't figure out a pattern among them. I've only seen number 4 happens one or two times.

---

Some pictures of the Firestore data that may be helpful to visualize the issue (sorry I wasn't able to screenshot the events):

[image: Item 2]
**Behavior 2**

[image: Item 3]
**Behavior 3**

[image: Item 4]
**Behavior 4**

Comment: are u using firebase transaction for updating the value?
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions

Comment: @ked Thanks for the suggestion, I just now tried implementing this way and the replacement problems is still going, however that's because I can't retreive all the documents fields, `snapshot.getData()` returns all the fields showed in the image except for 'alarmCount'. I'll try adding some changes in the collection creation as I suspect this is the problem.

Comment: @ked It worked!! After declaring `'alarmCount' = 0` when it's created I was able to update the field value with no problem, I still don't understant why this was such a huge hassle but hey, it's working fine now

Comment: ok, that's strange but good it's working

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as a Community Wiki, as the issue has already been fixed by the OP himself.

Since you already know that this field is going to be used anyway, initializing the document with `'alarmCount' = 0` is a good practice, that way you can make checks with a value instead of a check for null values and this might be a good way to mitigate these unexpected behaviors.

That being said, most of the behaviours you experienced are indeed a bit strange, and you could open a case in [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=530136&template=0) to figure out why this is happening.